# Error 500 in loop to create posts and thumbnails

Tags: thumbnails

I'm using this loop to read a folder, and create a custom post with the basename info.

But, around 20 images, the response is a error 500 and the process stops. I'm looking for some tip to do this faster. I have some like 1000 images. By the way, I think that problem is in

```
$attach_data  = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file);
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

but I'm not sure.

The loop is:

```
    public function run() {

    //  Caminho do servidor
    $where_read = ABSPATH . 'arquivos-ambientes';
    // $al_location = ABSPATH . 'upload/ambientes';

    // Pega apenas arquivos, ignorando o que não tiver extensão ( pastas )
    $files_array = glob( $where_read . "/*.{*}", GLOB_BRACE );

    $sufixo_amb = '-amb';
    $sufix_foto = 'foto-';

    $args = [
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'produtos_teste',
        'post_status'   => 'any'
    ];

    $all_products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $all_products as $ap ) {

        $slugs[]    = $ap->post_name;
        $post_ids[] = $ap->ID;

    }

    $ac = 'stringstringstringstringstringstring';
    foreach( $files_array as $file ) {

        $file_base_name = basename( $file, '.jpg' );
        $what_is_this[] = $file_base_name;

        $slugs_found = [];
        $products_ids = [];

        foreach( $slugs as $key => $s ) {

            $sm = strpos( $file_base_name, $s );

            if( $sm !== false ) {

                $file_names[] = $file_base_name;
                $slugs_found[] = $s;
                $products_ids[] = $post_ids[$key]; 

            }

        }

        $slugs_each[] = $slugs_found;
        $products_ids_each[] = $products_ids;

        if( substr( $file_base_name, 0, -2 ) == $ac ) {
            $galery_check = true;
        } else {
            $galery_check = false;
        }

        $ac = substr($file_base_name, 0, -2);

        $fotografo = ' ';
        if( strpos( $file_base_name, $sufix_foto ) !== false ) {

            if( strpos( $file_base_name, $sufix_foto ) !== false ) {

                $nome = $this->get_between_word( $file_base_name, $sufix_foto, $sufixo_amb );
                $fotografo = str_replace( '-', ' ', $nome );

            }

        }

        if( isset( $galery_check ) ) {

            $ambiente_name    = 'Ambiente Eliane: ' . str_replace('eliane-', '', $file_base_name);
            $ambientes[] = [

                'post_title'    => $ambiente_name,
                'base_name'     => $file_base_name,
                'ambiente'      => get_current_user_id(),
                'produtos'      => $products_ids,    //array id dos produtos
                'fotografia'    => $fotografo,
                'check'         => $galery_check,
                'file'          => $file

            ];

        }     

    }

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $last_one = count($ambientes);
    $counter = 0;
    // $category_id = 458;
    foreach( $ambientes as $amb ) {

        if( $amb['check'] === false ) {

            if( isset( $galeria ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $ind_post_id, 'galeria', $galeria ); 
                $aqui = [
                    'post_id' => $ind_post_id,
                    'galeria' => $galeria
                ];
                $update_galerias[] = $aqui;
            }

            $galeria = [];

            $image_url  = $amb['file'];
            $or_name    = $amb['file'];
            $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );
            $filename   = basename( $image_url );

            if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/ambientes/' . $filename;
            } else {
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/ambientes/' . $filename;
            }

            file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

            $attachment = [

                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'

            ];

            $attach_id  = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file);
            $att_ids[] = $attach_id . ' --- thumb ';
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

            // Gera os metadatas necessários para que os attachments funcionem normalmente.
            $attach_data  = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

            $status = 'publish';
            $in_args = [

                'post_title'    => $amb['post_title'],
                'post_content'  => '',
                'post_status'   => $status,
                'post_type'     => 'ambientes'

            ];

            $ind_post_id = wp_insert_post( $in_args );
            wp_set_object_terms( $ind_post_id, array(461), 'categoria-ambiente' );
            $ids_dos_ambientes[] = $ind_post_id;
            update_post_meta( $ind_post_id, 'ambiente', get_current_user_id() );
            update_post_meta( $ind_post_id, 'fotografia', $amb['fotografia'] );
            update_post_meta( $ind_post_id, 'produtos', $amb['produtos'] );
            set_post_thumbnail( $ind_post_id, $attach_id );
            unlink($or_name);

        } else {

            $image_url  = $amb['file'];
            $or_name    = $amb['file'];
            $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );
            $filename   = basename( $image_url );

            if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/ambientes/' . $filename;
            } else {
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/ambientes/' . $filename;
            }

            file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );
            $attachment = [

                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'

            ];

            $attach_id  = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file);
            $att_ids[] = $attach_id . ' --- galeria ';
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

            // Gera os metadatas necessários para que os attachments funcionem normalmente.
            $attach_data  = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
            $galeria[] = $attach_id;
            unlink($or_name);

        }

        $counter++;
        if( ( $counter ) == $last_one && $amb['check'] === true ) {
            update_post_meta( $ind_post_id, 'galeria', $galeria );
            $aqui = [
                'post_id' => $ind_post_id,
                'galeria' => $galeria
            ];
            $update_galerias[] = $aqui;
        }
    }

    $response = [
        'infos-nas-galerias' => $update_galerias,
        'att_ids'           => $att_ids,
        'ids_dos_ambientes' => $ids_dos_ambientes
    ];

    return $response;
}
```

You'll see some 'galeria' things, it's a meta of ACF, and this parts of code are working (the image galleries are okay).

get_between_word it's just a function to read some strings in basename.Well, my problem is with the images. When I run without use the wp_generate and wp_update everything works, but no thumbnails (the images with default sizes of wordpress) are created.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log? The error log might contain more information about the exact error.

Comment: I'll do this right now

Comment: I found thousands of 'Mon Sep 02 14:11:32 2019 1 177.40.37.14 466085 /home/elianecom/public_html/upload/produtos/eliane-panna-plus-po-60x60cm.jpg b _ i r elianecom ftp 1 * c', and, before 'ftp' it's the name of the file.

Comment: 500 errors with no obvious messages in the error log are often "out of memory" errors. If possible, try increasing the amount of memory available to PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: I recently increase to 512mb, but no changes in result. Any other idea?

Comment: Yes. Search the error log for the last ERROR in the list and include it in your question, not in this comment where it gets truncated. I can't tell from what you pasted what the error is.